# Is It Possible to Use Python Code with Pytorch Launched From Node JS?

Tags: python, node.js, pytorch, torch

I manage to launch python code in node js with below code.

```
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["./testcode/maincode/test_model/test.py","abc"]);
    pythonProcess.stdout.on("data",data=>{
        console.log(data.toString())
    })
```

the problem is that I want to use pytourch code with node js
but when I launch with below way,

```
 const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["./testcode/maincode/test_model/web_output.py","abc"]);
    pythonProcess.stdout.on("data",data=>{
        console.log(data.toString())
    })
```

it cause     `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'\r\n",`

I used to launch web_output.py with opening cmd
and command conda activate aip - > python web_output.py.

**is it possible to command conda activate aip then command python web_output.py with node js ?**

Comment: Yes. I think your problem is relative imports. Just remember that your working directory will be where you ran node. If you can ran it from the node folder using the same commands used in your program \then you should be able to run it from spawning a new process.

Comment: when you try to execute code from oode.js, you need to check how your other code import their required dependencies. You might have to provide the path via the third parameter of the spawn call `cwd`. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: but to use tourch or tensorflow , I think I have to use conda command...no? just execute python file from node js is done by    first part of code that I wrote